# Multiple category join with group_concat and category search

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to find all the category of a business with group concat by searching the business with specific category

```
|------ business -------- |
|-business_id
|-business_name
|-business_city

|------ business_cat_map ----|
|-id
|-business_id
|-cat_id

|------ cat --------------|
|-cat_id
|-cat_name
```

THis is simple multiple category relation

Now i want to query the database for the business whose category is (lets say Hotels) and return the details along with all the cats that business belongs to with group_concat().

I am playing with this kinda query but doesn't seem to work

```
SELECT  a.*
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_name) as cats
FROM    business a
        INNER JOIN business_cat_map b
        ON a.business_id = b.business_id
        INNER JOIN cat c 
        ON c.cat_id = b.cat_id 
WHERE cat_name = 'Motels'

GROUP BY a.business_id
```

I get the required business but only get Motels category in the group_concat() **[obviously due to the condition cat_name = 'Motels']**

So plz someone show me how to do this in single query. I don't want to use 2 queries.

HERE IS THE DATA

|------------ **business** -------------- |

|business_id|business_name|business_city

[image]

|------ **business_cat_map** --------------|

|------id------|---business_id---|--cat_id--|

[image]

|-------- **cat** ----------------|

|-----id-----|------cat_name----|

[image]

My query returns following

business_id|-business_name-|--cats--|

[image]

So here i just get a single cat but the business has more than one cats which i want to display in the cat column

Comment: please show sample records with your desired result

Comment: where is c.b_type_name in you tables?

Comment: Can you post current query output and your required output with some sample data..

Comment: An sqlfiddle would be good - TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT

Comment: sorry b_type_name is cat_name MY bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude here is your anser

```
SELECT a. * , GROUP_CONCAT( c.b_type_name ) 
FROM business a
INNER JOIN business_what b ON b.business_id = a.business_id
INNER JOIN business_type c ON c.b_type_id = b.b_type_id
WHERE b.business_id
IN (

SELECT business_what.business_id
FROM business_type
JOIN business_what ON business_type.b_type_id = business_what.b_type_id
WHERE business_type.b_type_name LIKE  '%Hotel%'
)
GROUP BY a.business_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.b_type_name) as cats
FROM    business a
        INNER JOIN business_cat_map b
        ON a.business_id = b.business_id
        INNER JOIN cat c 
        ON c.cat_id = b.cat_id 
WHERE a.business_id in (
        select x.business_id from business_cat_map AS x where x.cat_id = (
            select y.cat_id from cat AS y where y.cat_name = 'Hotels'
        )
        )

GROUP BY a.business_id
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but the query returns no rows